# Merging overlapp indices

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, intervals

I have a data.frame with start and end indices (sorted), for example:

```
df <- data.frame(start.idx = c(1,2,5),
                 end.idx = c(2,3,6))
```

I'm looking for a function that will merge rows `i` and `i-1` if `start.idx[i] == end.idx[i-1]`, such that the new row's `start.idx` will be `start.idx[i-1]` and `end.idx` will be `end.idx[i]`.

For the example above the resulting new (merged) data.frame will be:

```
res.df <- data.frame(start.idx = c(1,5),
                     end.idx = c(3,6))
```

Comment: This looks like a directed graph problem where you are looking for connected edges.  I think I would consider using igraph for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create groups which include rows in the same group if there is a overlap and then select the `first` and `last` value for start and end respectively.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(start.idx) %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(start.idx > lag(end.idx, default = 0))) %>%
  summarise(start.idx = first(start.idx), 
            end.idx = last(end.idx)) %>%
  select(-group)


#  start.idx end.idx
#      <dbl>   <dbl>
#1         1       3
#2         5       6
```